# Measuring traffic sent received

Tags: php, apache, wamp, wampserver

I'm using WAMP.
I want to measure the bytes sent and received while viewing the project.
How to do so ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clientside solution: If you are using firefox, the addon firebug ( https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/firebug/ ) can do this.

Serverside solution: You can specify the following in your apache log format (for your access log):

```
%...B:          Bytes sent, excluding HTTP headers.
%...b:          Bytes sent, excluding HTTP headers. In CLF format
```

> The "..." can be nothing at all (e.g.,
>   "%h %u %r %s %b"), or it can indicate
>   conditions for inclusion of the item
>   (which will cause it to be replaced
>   with "-" if the condition is not met).

See: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_log_config.html

Addition:
You will find something like this in your httpd.conf:

```
 LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common
 CustomLog logs/access_log common
```

which is easy to customize.

Comment: It seems that there is no way to log the received bytes with a custom log format.